# Clearing and restoring placeholder in UITextField

Tags: swift, uitextfield, placeholder

I have an `addTarget` set up on `UITextField` that clears the placeholder text when `editingDidBegin`. But I don't know how to restore the placeholder text if the user clicks on another `UITextField`, or the field is left empty.

This is located in `viewDidLoad()`

```swift
 firstInitialTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(clearPlaceholderInTextField), for: UIControl.Event.editingDidBegin)
```

This function is located in the main body of the program.

```swift
 @objc func clearPlaceholderInTextField() {

        firstInitialTextField.placeholder = ""

    }
```

I have several fields I would like to apply this same functionality to.

Comment: What's wrong with the standard functionality of the placeholder automatically disappearing once the user enters any text and it reappearing if the text is cleared?

Comment: BTW - resetting the placeholder after user leaves the field is only useful if the field has no text.

Comment: I was trying to have the text disappear once the ```UITextField``` was clicked on, not when text was being entered. I was trying to use that to draw focus to the field that is being edited.

Comment: Users are used to a placeholder being in view until they enter text. And the caret is a good indication of which text field is in focus.

Answer (score 0):

Create outlet collection for all the textfields like

```
@IBOutlet var textFs:[UITextField]!
```

with different tag for each , And array of placeHolders that you set in `viewDidLoad`

```
var placeholders = [String]()
```

Then set the vc as the delegate for all of them in `viewDidLoad`

```
textFs.forEach { $0.delegate = self }
```

Implement

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) { 
   textField.placeholder =  ""
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
   textField.placeholder =  placeholders[textField.tag]
}
```

Comment: When I add the ```IBOutlet``` an error appears: ```'weak' may only be applied to class and class-bound protocol types, not '[UITextField]'```